"Your device is managed by your organisation. Administrators can access the data in any profile on this device." Google Chrome on Work laptop
I logged in on my work laptop using my personal google ID.
My work laptop is running a windows 11 copy
I ony noticed it today that when adding a google ID to chrome, following message appers
Your device is managed by your organisation. Administrators can access the data in any profile on this device.
I would like to know how much data is my organization able to access about my personal account.
History?
Bookmarks?
Passwords?
Credit Cards?
any information is appericiated

Corporate admins can potentially access anything on their laptop. Advice: Don't use work laptops for personal stuff.

A domain administrator has full read-write access to every file in your system and potentially may have remote access, remote monitoring or endpoint protection tools which protect against copying data to unauthorised devices or networks. They could well have access to anything you type into that machine so if you do not trust your work then you should not trust the machine. As David says, a work machine should not be trusted as a personal machine. Many offices allow "minimal" personal use, but that does not mean you should have your entire life on it.

It is a positive thing to note about your organization: They give you continuous warning on-screen, not just when HR gives you corporate material to read and discard.
